# replacing a value based on value in other column, and leave as it is if condition not met

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a data-frame called `data`. Using `np.select()` I am replacing a value in column `data['CO BORROWER_STATUS']` based on one condition given in column `[data['CO BORROWER NAME']`

1. If `[data['CO BORROWER NAME'] == 'NOT_AVAILABLE'` I will change `data['CO BORROWER_STATUS']= 'NOT_AVAILABLE'`

2.If not there should be no change in the column `data['CO BORROWER_STATUS']`

I used np.select() method as shown below, but this replaces the entries to 0 if the condition not met. Is there any other changes We can do with the code to leave the default value without any change if the condition not met.

I need the answer using np.select() only or any other efficient methods, not others which will be not efficient, any ideas please ?

```
data['CO BORROWER_STATUS'] = np.select([data['CO BORROWER NAME'] == 'NOT_AVAILABLE'],['NOT_AVAILABLE'])

o/p-->:    
I am not passing the else argument here, hence the values are replaced 
with 0 in default for data['CO BORROWER_STATUS'] if condition fails.

Can I have no change if condition not met.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) set last parameter `default` to original values:

```
data['CO BORROWER_STATUS'] = np.select([data['CO BORROWER NAME'] == 'NOT_AVAILABLE'],
                                       ['NOT_AVAILABLE'], 
                                       default=data['CO BORROWER NAME'])
```

Because only one condition, better is [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here:

```
data['CO BORROWER_STATUS'] = np.where(data['CO BORROWER NAME'] == 'NOT_AVAILABLE',
                                      'NOT_AVAILABLE', 
                                      data['CO BORROWER NAME'])
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael , both np.select() and np.where() working efficiently !!